# What skill is used to rile a crowd?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills

A player wants his bard be a revolutionary of sorts, riling the populace to rise against their oppressors, but I'm not sure if the skill the bard should use to do that is Perform (oratory) or Diplomacy as both seem valid candidates. Which one is it?

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't list bluff?  I could make an answer to that end but you give two options here=)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Perform](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#perform) (oratory) typically only raises money

When a creature makes a [Perform](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#perform) (oratory) skill check, the creature's attempting to scare up some pocket change by entertaining the audience with its speech. The effect that entertainment may have on the listeners is beyond the orator's control: the DM decides if there even *is* an effect *at all*, likely basing his judgment on the player's description of his PC's oration, the general attitude of the orator's audience, and the Perform (oratory) skill check's result. That is, the oration's *content* isn't really important mechanically—the amount that the audience donates to the orator's cause depends solely upon the Perform (oratory) check's result, making it possible for an 8-hour speech about the horrors of the current government to elicit as much in donations as an 8-hour speech about the myriad of fascinating ways paint can dry.

(The *Player's Handbook* on the skill Perform says, "Trying to earn money by playing [i.e. *performing*] in public requires anywhere from an evening’s work to a full day’s performance" (79), hence the *8 hours* figure above. This DM reduces the amount earned with a Perform check commensurately with the time spent performing if performing less than 8 hours. So, for example, a 1-hour check yields 1/8 the normal amount, a 10-min. check yields 1/48 the normal amount, and so on. Also, Perform checks that are made by folks other than bards and that are *not* made to earn money *are*, apparently, a thing, but they've no mechanical effect in the core rules.)<sup>1</sup>

## [Diplomacy](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#diplomacy) changes attitudes toward the diplomat

On the other hand, successfully using the skill [Diplomacy](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#diplomacy) allows the diplomat to "change the attitudes of others," with one of the skill's introductory examples involving convincing "the ogre mages that have captured you that they should ransom you back to your friends instead of twisting your limbs off one by one" (*PH* 71). So, by default, the skill Diplomacy *can* work on groups of creatures, although it's unspecified exactly on *how many* it can work against *at once*. In addition, a successful Diplomacy skill check made to change one or more creatures' attitudes only potentially changes those creatures' attitudes *toward the diplomat*—not toward, for example, an individual, a group, or a cause. The skill Diplomacy can make listeners like *you*, but it won't make listeners like [stilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stilton_cheese) or [Equifax](https://www.usatoday.com/story/money/business/2018/02/01/bad-reputation-americas-top-20-most-hated-companies/1058718001/).

However, listeners that like the diplomat *enough* may be willing to follow him in his crusade. That is, folks that possess toward the diplomat an attitude of at least *friendly* will provide him limited aid, folks that are at least *helpful* will take risks to help the diplomat, and folks that are [*fanatic*](http://dndsrd.net/epicSkills.html#diplomacy) are, for a time, ready to die for him! Again, though, *it doesn't matter* the diplomat's cause. The diplomat has merely persuaded his audience that he's a freakin' *boss*, and whether the diplomat's cause is saving Delta House from Dean Wormer, making folks believe he's doing the right thing for Teldar Paper, or rebuilding after a devastating meteor strike, folks will—if the Diplomacy skill check is high enough—do stuff *for him* and *not* because they have any particular attachment to what he's talking about.

> #### Using Perform instead of Diplomacy
>
> The *Epic Level Handbook* on the skill Perform says that the Perform skill can be used to "sway an audience's attitude with your performance" (42) then presents again the same kind of attitudes chart as is included with the skill Diplomacy except that the DCs to sway an audience's attitude using the skill Perform are *20 higher* than those needed to sway the identical attitudes using the skill Diplomacy! (The *SRD* instead repeats in the epic [Perform](http://dndsrd.net/epicSkills.html#perform) skill description the chart from the epic Diplomacy skill description. The *SRD*'s handling of epic skills keeps *3e* legacy text (q.v. the epic skill Handle Animal) and—in this reader's opinion—appears to've been hastily compiled. So, although it pains this reader to say it, his instinct is to trust that the *Epic Level Handbook* DCs are, in fact, accurate rather than ascribing stealth errata to the *SRD*.)
>
> No further information is given about what, exactly, swaying an audience's attitude *means*, so this reader assumes—given the presence of the Diplomacy skill attitude chart—that doing so otherwise works like the Diplomacy skill: because of the performance the audience likes (or dislikes) the performer more rather than because of the performance the audience, for example, now likes (or dislikes) cats or the harpsichord. Also the text is silent on *how long* it takes a performer to sway an audience, forcing the DM—if he opts to use these rules at all—to make that decision.

### What the player may *actually* want

What I suspect the player *really* wants—because it's *awesome*—is for his PC to be able to change an audience's attitude toward things *other* than his PC; he wants the PC's audience to, for example, embrace or loathe a particular art, food, organization, or pet *because his PC said to*. That is, the player *doesn't care* if the audience likes or dislikes *his PC* but if the PC's audience loves or hates the subject of the PC's rant.

That's *possible*, but that's not a *normal* use of the Diplomacy skill nor of any Perform skill. The DM must *either* devise house rules to enable the diplomat or performer to do that *or* allow into the campaign feats like the ancestor feats **Renowned Courtesan** (*Dragon* #315 65) or the superior **Silver Tongue** (*Oriental Adventures* 65–6 yet the feat's benefit's changed by the *Dragon* #318 article "Oriental Adventures Update: Eastern Flavor" (32–48))—both only available at level 1—or feats like **Seelie** or **Unseelie Court Noble Kelir** (from the Fey Feature Web column [“Life in a Noble House”](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/fey/20030815a))—both having difficult-to-meet prerequisites or mandating a convoluted PC background.

Keep in mind, though, that, as written, such feats in the right campaign (and, arguably, in *any* campaign) are *extremely* powerful. Being able to mundanely and forever twist the hearts and minds of other creatures so that they love or hate what they previously hated or loved has profound consequences on the narrative landscape. Seriously, if PCs have feats like these, other folks in the campaign *must* have feats like these so that there's at least the illusion of stability; without that balance, the PCs will quickly raise an empire… or hurl the campaign setting into anarchy.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> For those wondering why this DM even *has* a house rule for this, the more-adventurer-friendly skills Sleight of Hand and Tumble can *also* be used to earn money like the skill Perform, and those're what this DM's seen PCs use more often. That is, sometimes PCs are at loose ends—stuck waiting in a town for a magic item to be created, for example—and, to pass the hours or days, the PCs use their skills to earn pocket change. Usually, it's enough to overnight at a nice inn so the player doesn't have to erase gp from his character sheet.

Answer (score 4):

This is DM call. Here's how I work it as a DM. The most basic answer to your question is actually a question:

**What is the character doing?** Are they making a speech a la "I have a Dream" in front of a large gathered crowd? That would be Oratory. If they specifically call out someone in the crowd--diplomacy, a la "To Kill a Mockingbird" when Atticus talks down the mob by getting specific and addressing them as people rather than as a mob/group.

**Diplomacy is about making contact with decision-makers and engaging with them. Oratory is about the general mood.**

**So it might be a combo.** Your speaker starts with Oratory. Maybe it works on the general crowd, a bit, but some of the "taste-makers" or leaders in the room remain skeptical. If he speaks to them specifically or asks them what their issue is, addressing it, that will be diplomacy. A great roll on that will help boost the oratory, as they go back to addressing the crowd...and so on.

**As always, this is DM call, but I use those rules of thumb as far as determining which they are using.**

Perform Oratory seems to the be best fit, if you don't want to do all that. Oratory is about moving an audience, diplomacy isn't as much. Keep in mind that with Oratory he can change the mood of the crowd but he won't have much control of what they do. So you can rile people up, but getting them to take a specific action is harder. It can lead to the people burning down their own town rather than going to the Lord's house and tarring and feathering them.

Comment: @KRyan This answer is, as I state, DM 's call, but this is the logic I follow.

Comment: Kudos on the edit, and +1 (sadly, ish, I did not downvote originally, so I can’t un-downvote—hopefully those who did will check back and reconsider their vote).

Answer (score 3):

## The higher one

When a character has two skills that are equally valid for a given check, in games where the GM is telling the player what skill to roll, you ought to use the higher one.  For a bard this is probably Perform(Oratory), but maybe not.

This is in part because you ought to be working with, rather than against, your players at the meta level of the game, but also because choosing the other skill does nothing but slow the game down.

If both skills are roughly equally applicable to what you think the player has described and you choose the lower skill, the player will just alter their action at that point, or in the future if you force them not to alter it immediately/retroactively, to instead select the higher skill.  Essentially you are just making them guess what you've secretly made up as the code to get to use the skill they picked, and that's not usually conducive to having a good RPG.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest setting a Perform (Oratory) DC to command a crowd's attention, and then a seperate Diplomacy or Bluff check to sway them according to the normal rules.

I would scale the Oratory check up with the size of the crowd and with chaotic conditions that would make it hard to get a crowd to listen, (like a riot or a battle).

I would scale it down for terrain features that would tend to direct a crowd's attention at the orator anyway. Ideal conditions would be in a theater with the orator on stage. The next best would be at the center of a town square with an elevation advantage over the crowd. No bonus for trying to get the attention of a crowd that is going about its own business on the street at eye level with the orator.

Comment: Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.